# List comprehension to list elements of list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists in python, just like such:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

And I want to create a list comprehension that will output it's elements in a list, as such:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

I tried doing `[c for c in b for b in a]` but it is now working. What am I screwing up? : )

Comment: Swap the two for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for that:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain(*a)))
% gives: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

or simply:

```
print([v for sublist in a for v in sublist])
% gives: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```